# How to plot multiple variables in X axis in ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2

I have an excel file containing the data shown here. I want to create a dot plot using ggplot2. I want to put mutations (shown in column) in X axis and Clade (shown in Rows like Alpha, Beta, Gamma etc.) in Y axis. I can't put multiple variables in X axis.

[image]

Comment: You'd probably have to `tidyr::pivot_longer()` to reshape the data from wide to long format.

Comment: Hi! Is it possible to share with us a reproducible example?
However, you'll have to use the `pivot_longer` function of the `tidyr` package before using the `ggplot2` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot teunbrand & Luis. I have tried tidyr and able to perform what I intended to do. Thanks again.

Comment: Next time provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example with your code read in and what you have tried.